# Java Spring application does not reflect updated code changes

Tags: java, spring

For an university assignment, I am supposed to encode a certain string using SHA-256. The file to edit is called ServerApplication.java, and it originally has this code:

```
    package com.snhu.sslserver;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;



@SpringBootApplication
public class ServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}

@RestController
class ServerController{
//FIXME:  Add hash function to return the checksum value for the data string that should contain your name.    
    @RequestMapping("/hash")
    public String myHash(){
        String data = "Hello Joe Smith!";
       
        return "<p>data:"+data;
    }
}
```

Upon running the application I can then access https:/localhost:8443/hash and I will see the following output:

```
data: Hello Joe Smith!
```

If I edit the code above on String data = "Hello My Name!" Instead of Joe Smith, and rerun the application, and refresh localhost, it still says Hello Joe Smith! I have tried using different browsers to test and my changes are not saved.

Could I get some help please? Let me know if additional code is needed, there are some Maven dependencies and the Spring framework.

Comment: This seems to be a "problem" with your IDE, not your application. What IDE are you using?

Comment: I am using Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 2023-03 which I got from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/installer

Comment: Ok. nothing wrong with it, but Spring has a "special" flavor of it, called [Spring Tools Suite](https://spring.io/tools). It's just a reskin of Eclipse, really. Additionally, you could try the [suggestions from the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.hotswapping).